# Cython: share pure python module

Tags: python, cython

I have one pure python module `a.py` file containing a class enhanced with cython:

```
@cython.cclass
class Test
```

How can I use this class in another pure python module `b.py`? I tried `from a import Test` but then the cython compiler tells me `Not a type` wherever I use `Test` in `b.py`

Comment: I suspect you have to create a .pxd definition file for both `a.py` and `b.py` and define the types there. Unfortunately, it involves duplicating information in two places, but it doesn't break the ability to use `a.py` and `.b.py` from plain Python.

Comment: I tried that, but then the cython compilation does not work anymore. For the reason that you cannot use `cimport` in a `.py`file to share the definition file

Comment: If you're defining the type of a function argument you could put the cimport in b.pxd file. If you're defining a type within a function I don't think you can though (in which case I don't know!)

Comment: Actually I think you can (see "magic attributes within the pxd" in the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can do it by using `.pxd` files in addition to the `.py` files to specify the types in. I realise this isn't as elegant as putting everything in the `.py` files, but as far as I know it's the best you can do.

a.py:

```
class Test:
    pass
```

a.pxd:

```
cdef class Test:
  pass
```

b.py:

```
# here I use Test in all the places I think you could want to use it:
#   as a function argument
#   as a variable in a function
#   in a class
import a

def f(x):
    return x

def g():
    t = a.Test()
    return t

class C:
    pass
```

b.pxd:

```
import cython
cimport a

cpdef f(a.Test x)

@cython.locals(t=a.Test)
cpdef g()

cdef class C:
    cdef a.Test t
```

You can verify that it's using the type information correctly by inspecting the generated `b.c` file.

For reference, the relevant documentation is http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html#magic-attributes-within-the-pxd

Comment: works! I never thought of creating also a pxd file for `b.py`